# Getting "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'" error while updating an object in django

Tags: python, django, model

I want to update an object using UpdateView in django. The update was working until I used inline formset. After using this, the weird problem is happening.

views.py:

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Update a created a employee
    """

    login_url = '/authentication/login/'
    template_name = 'employee/employee_update_form.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddModelForm
    # work_form_class = WorkExperienceForm
    # education_form_class = EducationForm
    work_formset_class = WorkExperienceFormset
    education_formset_class = EducationFormset
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()

    # Override default get method
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        # work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee)
        # education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee)

        form = self.form_class(instance=employee)
        # work_form = self.work_form_class(prefix='work_form', instance=work_info)
        # education_form = self.education_form_class(prefix='education_form',instance=education_info)
        work_formset = self.work_formset_class(request.GET or None, instance=employee)
        education_formset = self.education_formset_class(request.GET or None, instance=employee)

        print("Employee ID: ", employee)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_formset': work_formset,
                                                    'education_formset': education_formset,
                                                    'supervisor_assigned': employee.supervisor_select
                                                    }
                                                )
    # Override default post method
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        # work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee)
        # education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee)

        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=employee)
        # work_form = self.work_form_class(request.POST, prefix='work_form', instance=work_info)
        # education_form = self.education_form_class(request.POST, prefix='education_form',instance=education_info)
        work_formset = self.work_formset_class(request.POST, instance=employee)
        education_formset = self.education_formset_class(request.POST, instance=employee)

        # Check form validation
        if form.is_valid() and work_formset.is_valid() and education_formset.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            # Save work experience
            for work_form in work_formset:
                work = work_form.save(commit=False)
                work.employee_id = instance.id
                work.save()

            # Save education experience
            for education_form in education_formset:
                education = education_form.save(commit=False)
                education.employee_id = instance.id
                education.save()

            return redirect('employee:employee-list')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_formset': work_formset,
                                                    'education_formset': education_formset
                                                    }
                                                )
```

When I press Update button in my update form, 'id' this field is required - error is giving. But 'id' is primary key and it is auto incremental, I can not pass this value.

models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Create employee attributes
    """

    employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, parent_link=True)
    e_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True) 

class WorkExperience(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee previous work experiences
    """
    #employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, parent_link=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='we_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    previous_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    job_designation = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

class Education(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee education background
    """
    #employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, parent_link=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='edu_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    institution_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    passing_year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    result = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

error message:

```
File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
    
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Documents\nextgen-hrm\hrm\employee\views.py", line 429, in get
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1351, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1378, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1312, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1166, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 72, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.
```

How can I solve this issue? I think my query is not correct.

EDIT:

```
class SupervisorLoadAJAX(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/authentication/login/'

    def get(self, request):
        id = request.GET.get("id", None)
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        if employee:
            supervisor = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
            print(str(supervisor)+" has been loaded")
            data = {
                 'loaded': True,
                 'supervisor_id': id,
                 'supervisor_first_name': supervisor.first_name,
                 'supervisor_last_name': supervisor.last_name,
                 'supervisor_designation': supervisor.designation.designation_name
                }
        else:
            data = {
                 'loaded': False
                }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**EDIT: Added fronted error messgae:**

when I click the update button 'This field is required' message is popping up for 'id' field. But I am not supposed to pass id. why this showing.

[image]

Comment: make sure `id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")` id is available in kwargs

Comment: Yeah. it is available. I can see every filled data in the frontend. But when i submit updated form, this error occurs

Comment: see `employee\views.py` 429 number line. Here, `employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)` here `id` would be `_id`

Comment: That line is not associated with this view. That line is associated with another view where id is declared as id

Comment: can u post that code portion

Comment: `id = request.GET.get("id", None)` what u get in this line?

Comment: an object id. not value

Comment: not value means?

Comment: it returns 'employee object (1)' . not 1, 2 etc.

Comment: @shafik - did you find anything?

Comment: No. I didn't check. I think you miss some portion of code which cause the error. Problem was somewhere you try to filter with `id` but id value you pass is `None`

Comment: How can I find which portion is causing the error?

Comment: check this file `File "C:\Users\ZulkarNayem\Documents\nextgen-hrm\hrm\employee\views.py", line 429, in get
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219594/discussion-between-shafik-and-fahim-irfan).